# ASP.NET MVC home button displays another button when I change the bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I created a default MVC app and then changed the default bootstrap for layout, but the nav bar went like this whatever bootstrap file I use instead of the nav buttons spread out[image]

how can I fix this or did I do something wrong?
this is the BundleConfig code

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/freelancer.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: Use F12 to debug the browser. Check the layout file and viewstart in shared folder too.

Comment: tried it, there was nothing wrong. i tried it several time but the same results, that button always appears and the other navigation buttons are hidden instead of spread out when full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the bootstrap version. I had the same problem with the default application when I upgraded to bootstrap 4.41. See what version you have installed currently, if it's 4.0 or higher try uninstalling and reinstalling 3.41 and make sure any add bootstraps are created for this version. 
Hopefully this helps